# Reference pgfplots' groupplot with subcaption

Tags: pgfplots, labels, subcaption

I created a groupplot with pgfplots. For referencing each plot I added a subcaption within a node into each plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2}]
            \nextgroupplot
            \node [text width=1em,anchor=north west] at (rel axis cs: 0,1) {\captionof{subfigure}{\label{fig:a}}};
            \addplot plot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2) (3,3)};
            \nextgroupplot
            \node [text width=1em,anchor=north west] at (rel axis cs: 0,1) {\captionof{subfigure}{\label{fig:b}}};
            \addplot plot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,4) (3,9)};
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Figure}
\end{figure}
Figure \ref{fig:a} and \ref{fig:b}?!?
\end{document}
```

The problem is: the counter is wrong. The subfigure 1a is referenced as 0a. The same behavior in my whole document, e. g. 4b gets 3b.

[image: Wrong references of subcaptions.]

Comment: Use `\subcaption{\label{fig:a}}`.

Comment: Yes, that's it's! Thanks! Unfortunately all examples have used the `\captionof`. Copy your comment into an answer and I can mark it as answered.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/44/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `\subcaption{\label{fig:a}}` and `\subcaption{\label{fig:b}}` to set the subcaptions.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}% <- added, current version is 1.13
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2}]
            \nextgroupplot
            \node [text width=1em,anchor=north west] at (rel axis cs: 0,1)
                {\subcaption{\label{fig:a}}};%<- changed
            \addplot plot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2) (3,3)};
            \nextgroupplot
            \node [text width=1em,anchor=north west] at (rel axis cs: 0,1) 
                {\subcaption{\label{fig:b}}};%<- changed
            \addplot plot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,4) (3,9)};
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Figure}
\end{figure}
Figure \ref{fig:a} and \ref{fig:b}?!?
\end{document}
```

Note that it is useful to set a `compat` value.